# Consulting values of the first order temporal correlation coefficient CORT when clustering time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, cluster-analysis

I am doing cluster analysis of several time series in `R` (the sales of a product in different stores).

I am using the first order temporal correlation coefficient `CORT(S1,S2)`, in package `TSclust`, where `S1` and `S2` are two time series.

The literaure (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSclust/TSclust.pdf) explains that `CORT` belongs to the `interval [-1,1]`: when `CORT(S1,S2)=1` both series show a similar dynamic behavior, and when `CORT(S1,S2)=-1` they have opposite behavior.

I would like to know how to see the results of `CORT`, in order to observe the values of `CORT` for each pair of time series.

We can see the next example in `TSclust` package:

```
## Create three sample time series
x <- cumsum(rnorm(100))
y <- cumsum(rnorm(100))
z <- sin(seq(0, pi, length.out=100))

## Compute the distance and check for coherent results
diss.CORT(x, y, 2)
diss.CORT(x, z, 2)
diss.CORT(y, z, 2)
```

So with the above code we can calculate de dissimilarity index using the coefficient `CORT(S1,S2)`, but we cannot consult the values of the `CORT` coefficient.

So, does anyone how to see the values of `CORT` coefficient in `R`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but any how this is what I did:

```
View(diss.CORT)
```

where R shows:

```
function (x, y, k = 2, deltamethod = "Euclid") 

{
  .ts.sanity.check(x, y)
  .check.equal.length.ts(x, y)
  corrt <- corrtemporder1(x, y)
  type <- (pmatch(deltamethod, c("Euclid", "Frechet", "DTW")))
  typedist <- 0
  if (is.na(type)) {
    stop(paste("Unknown method", deltamethod))
  }
  else if (type == 1) {
    typedist <- as.numeric(dist(rbind(x, y)))
  }
  else if (type == 2) {
    typedist <- diss.FRECHET(x, y)
  }
  else if (type == 3) {
    typedist <- dtw(x, y, dist.method = "Manhattan", distance.only = T)$distance
  }
  (2/(1 + exp(k * corrt))) * typedist
}
```

Now if you go through that and start reading the script it seems that you are looking for line where `corrt <- corrtemporder1(x, y)`. google it and you get to: https://github.com/cran/TSclust/blob/master/R/diss.R

```
#############################################################################
#################   Temporal Correlation Distance   #########################
#############################################################################

##CHOUAKRIA-DOUZAL

corrtemporder1 <- function (x, y) {
    p <- length(x)
    sum((x[2:p] - x[1:(p-1)]) * (y[2:p] - y[1:(p-1)])) / ( sqrt( sum((x[2:p] - x[1:(p-1)])^2) ) * sqrt( sum((y[2:p] - y[1:(p-1)])^2) ))
}
```

Now, I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you so much, this is what I was looking for! Now, I would like to do it for 30 time series, I would like to plot the `CORT` matrix, as we do with the command `corrplot`. Do you know if there is a way to do it with `CORT`?

Comment: I have done it, but I get the message: "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: @AnaA appreciate it! Thanks